# Error message in script that I copied and pasted: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of null

Tags: null, typeerror

I followed the example exactly on the Google Help site to create a Conference scheduling form. It works perfectly in the sample but hangs up when I try to run it.
I get this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of null.

I copied the set up of the spreadsheet exactly and formatted all of the cells just like the sample. What am I missing?

I do not know how to fix script problems so I need some help!

Comment: What is the actual code are you having problems with?

Comment: It won't let me paste it...it's 5000 characters too long!  Any suggestions?

Comment: When I try to Debug the script, it says there is an error on this line: var user = {name: e.namedValues['Name'][0], email: e.namedValues['Email'][0]};